# C pointer error, got exc_bad_access code=2, address0x100000000

Tags: c, xcode, pointers, exc-bad-access

I'm so confused about this error. I wrote a code to separate a set. When I run it, sometimes it works, sometimes got the exc_bad_access code=2 error. Here is the code:

```
typedef struct vertexSet {
    int numVertexSet;
    int* set1;
    int* set2;
} set;

set* bipatitionSet(int Vertex) {

    if (Vertex%2){
        Vertex +=1;
    }

    set* set;
    set = malloc(sizeof(set));
    set->numVertexSet = Vertex/2;
    set->set1 = calloc(set->numVertexSet,sizeof(int));
    set->set2 = calloc(set->numVertexSet,sizeof(int));

    if (set == NULL) {
        printf("Set memory allocated error!");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (set->set1 ==NULL||set->set2==NULL) {
        free(set);
        printf("Set memory allocated error!");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i=0; i< set->numVertexSet; i++) {
        set->set1[i] = i;
        set->set2[i] = i + set->numVertexSet;// got error here
    }

    return set;
}
```

When I run it, I found the set2 address is changed in the for loop, and the value of set2[0] becomes -17958193. This error comes out sometimes but not all the time. Can someone explain why and how to fix the error? I checked that there is no address confliction.

Comment: Please don't name variables the same as types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't name a variable the same as a type, since the variable will shadow the type (And how do you understand your own code, and tell the difference between types and variables?). In this case "shadow" is similar in meaning to "overwrite".

As an example, your `malloc` is incorrect, since `sizeof(set)` will be the size of the variable `set`, a simple 4 or 8 byte pointer, not the size of your 12-20 byte `struct vertexSet`.